# Alternative to CSV-Array Conversion to Fetch Data Faster

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, csv, phonegap

I built an app with Cordova/PhoneGap and used a naive approach to fetch data. I just converted my two (tab-separated) CSV files to arrays, and then ran some lookup functions (not shown) on those arrays.

```
    // Load the rankings.csv file and define its parameters.
var requests = new XMLHttpRequest(); // You only need one XMLHttpRequest() object.
requests.open("GET", "docs/rankings.csv", false);
requests.send(null);
var l2Ranks = [];
var jsoRanks = requests.responseText.split("\n");
for (x = 0; x < jsoRanks.length; x++) {
  l2Ranks.push(jsoRanks[x].split("\t"));
  for (y = 0; y < l2Ranks.length; y++) {
    for (z = 0; z < l2Ranks[y].length; z++) {
      l2Ranks[y][z] = Number(l2Ranks[y][z]);
    }
  }
}
// Load the sentences.csv file and define its parameters.
requests.open("GET", "docs/sentences.csv", false);
requests.send(null);
var l2Sents = [];
var jsoSents = requests.responseText.split("\n");
for (x = 0; x < jsoSents.length; x++) {
  l2Sents.push(jsoSents[x].split("\t"));
  for (y = 0; y < l2Sents.length; y++) {
    l2Sents[y][0] = Number(l2Sents[y][0]);
  }
}
```

Now, this worked okay when the CSV files were smaller. However, the load times have become noticeably longer. I was initially going to mask it with a load screen, but I suspect there's a faster way to usefully load my data.

So I've considered a few options:

1. I could try CSV streaming with [csv-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stream) or [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv), but I haven't seen an example of how to fetch data via this method.
2. I could convert the CSV files to a JSON files, and just run off of those, but don't know what benefits there are to its speed.
3. I could do a regex text search over the CSV file, but again, I don't know if constantly opening a file that's 5MB in a size and growing will make it faster.

Which of these would be faster? Also, with respect to option (1), what would a simple lookup function (akin to INDEX(MATCH()) in spreadsheet software) look like?

Currently, my other functions (not shown) find a specified column of l2Ranks, get its ID number for it (the 0th item in both l2Ranks and l2Sents), and then return the l2Sents item that matches the same specified column and the row containing the ID number. There is zero slowdown there.

Comment: Just use JSON, it is very fast.

Comment: Is there a reason why it would be faster in my case?